# PhP. Facebook share results in incorrect thumbnail and information

Tags: php, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I am trying to add links in my article from which you can share the article on social media.

I have used the following links.

**For Facebook**

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.example_site.com/tenx_blog_latest/blogs/admin/post-detail.php?article_id=<?php echo $article_id?>">
   <img src="pos-imag/fb.png"></a>
```

When i share this on facebook it is succefuly the correct link but the thumbnail and textual information in taken from the home page of my website.

Same Goes for Twitter.com

Can somebody guide me how can i correct this.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the Facebook and Twitter debugger tools to validate the sharing URLs contents and meta tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

You need to log in from your Facebook and Twitter accounts to access these pages.